# qsort struct not doing as supposed to

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, struct, qsort

Hi  so I'm trying to sort my struct with qsort and it sort of works but not really...
Can anyone tell me what's happening and why it goes wrong ? :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int el_cmp(const void *ep1, const void *ep2);

typedef struct kort
{
    int kuloer;
    int vaerdi;
} kort;

int main(void){
    int i; 
    int k[] = {3, 4, 5, 6};
    int v[] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14};
    
    kort kort[52];

    for (i = 0; i < 52; i++){

        kort[i].kuloer = k[i % 4];
        kort[i].vaerdi = v[i % 13];

        
    }
    printf("\n");

    qsort(kort, 52, sizeof(int), el_cmp);
 
    for (i = 0; i < 52; i++){

        printf("Kort%d: %d %d\n", i + 1, kort[i].kuloer, kort[i].vaerdi);
    }
     

    return(0);
}

int el_cmp(const void *ep1, const void *ep2){
    int *tp1 = (int*) ep1,
        *tp2 = (int*) ep2;

    if (*tp1 < *tp2){
        return -1;
    } else if (*tp1 > *tp2){
        return 1;
    } else return 0;
}
```

the result is this:

Kort1: 2 2

Kort2: 3 3

Kort3: 3 3

Kort4: 3 3

...
Kort5: 3 3,
Kort6: 3 4,
Kort7: 4 4,
Kort8: 4 4,
Kort9: 4 4,
Kort10: 4 4,
Kort11: 5 5,
Kort12: 5 5,
Kort13: 5 5,
Kort14: 5 5,
Kort15: 6 6,
Kort16: 6 6
Kort17: 6 6,
Kort18: 6 6,
Kort19: 7 7,
Kort20: 8 8,
Kort21: 9 9,
Kort22: 10 10,
Kort23: 11 11,
Kort24: 12 12,
Kort25: 13 13,
Kort26: 14 14,

Kort27: 5 2

Kort28: 6 3

Kort29: 3 4

...
Kort30: 4 5,
Kort31: 5 6,
Kort32: 6 7,
Kort33: 3 8,
Kort34: 4 9,
Kort35: 5 10,
Kort36: 6 11,
Kort37: 3 12,
Kort38: 4 13,
Kort39: 5 14,
Kort40: 6 2,
Kort41: 3 3,
Kort42: 4 4,
Kort43: 5 5,
Kort44: 6 6,
Kort45: 3 7,
Kort46: 4 8,
Kort47: 5 9,
Kort48: 6 10,
Kort49: 3 11,
Kort50: 4 12,
Kort51: 5 13,
Kort52: 6 14,

but I'm expecting this:

Kort1: 3 2

Kort2: 3 3

Kort3: 3 4

Kort4: 3 5

...
Kort5: 3 6,
Kort6: 3 7,
Kort7: 3 8,
Kort8: 3 9,
Kort9: 3 10,
Kort10: 3 11,
Kort11: 3 12,
Kort12: 3 13,
Kort13: 3 14,

Kort14: 4 2

Kort15: 4 3

...
Kort16: 4 4,
Kort17: 4 5,
Kort18: 4 6,
Kort19: 4 7,
Kort20: 4 8,
Kort21: 4 9,
Kort22: 4 10,
Kort23: 4 11,
Kort24: 4 12,
Kort25: 4 13,
Kort26: 4 14,

...
Kort27: 5 2,
Kort28: 5 3,
Kort29: 5 4,
Kort30: 5 5,
Kort31: 5 6,
Kort32: 5 7,
Kort33: 5 8,
Kort34: 5 9,
Kort35: 5 10,
Kort36: 5 11,
Kort37: 5 12,
Kort38: 5 13,
Kort39: 5 14,

...
Kort40: 6 2,
Kort41: 6 3,
Kort42: 6 4,
Kort43: 6 5,
Kort44: 6 6,
Kort45: 6 7,
Kort46: 6 8,
Kort47: 6 9,
Kort48: 6 10,
Kort49: 6 11,
Kort50: 6 12,
Kort51: 6 13,
Kort52: 6 14,

Comment: You have an array of `kort`s, but you're sorting them as if it's an array of `int`s.

Comment: You tell `qsort()` that the objects being sorted have the same size as an `int`, but they don't.  Because type `kort` has an `int` as its first member, the comparison function can get away with pretending that the objects are `int`s, but `qsort()` cannot work correctly without the correct element size.

Comment: That works for the left side... but right side numbers are still random

Comment: As written, your comparison function takes only the the first member of each `kort` into account, and then only because that member happens to have type `int`, matching the casts performed by the function.  If you want to take both members into account for ordering, then you need to write the comparison function to do so, which would involve it acknowledging that the array elements have type `kort`, not `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters it is a bad idea to redeclare the name `kort`

```
kort kort[52];
```

Nevertheless this call of `qsort`

```
qsort(kort, 52, sizeof(int), el_cmp);
```

is incorrect. You have an array of structures of the type `struct kort` not of the type `int`. The call of `qsort` can look the following way

```
qsort(kort, sizeof( kort ) / sizeof( *kort ), sizeof( *kort ), el_cmp);
```

The comparison function can look the following way

```
int el_cmp( const void *ep1, const void *ep2 )
{
    const struct kort *a = ep1;
    const struct kort *b = ep2;

    int result = ( b->kuloer < a->kuloer ) - ( a->kuloer < b->kuloer );

    if ( result == 0 )
    {
        result = ( b->vaerdi < a->vaerdi ) - ( a->vaerdi < b->vaerdi );
    }

    return result;
}
```

Here is your updated program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct kort
{
    int kuloer;
    int vaerdi;
} kort;

int el_cmp( const void *ep1, const void *ep2 )
{
    const struct kort *a = ep1;
    const struct kort *b = ep2;

    int result = ( b->kuloer < a->kuloer ) - ( a->kuloer < b->kuloer );

    if (result == 0)
    {
        result = ( b->vaerdi < a->vaerdi ) - ( a->vaerdi < b->vaerdi );
    }

    return result;
}

int main( void )
{
    int k[] = { 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    int v[] = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 };

    const size_t k_size = sizeof( k ) / sizeof( *k );
    const size_t v_size = sizeof( v ) / sizeof( *v );

    enum { N = 52 };

    kort kort[N];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
    {

        kort[i].kuloer = k[i % k_size];
        kort[i].vaerdi = v[i % v_size];
    }

    qsort( kort, N, sizeof( *kort ), el_cmp );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
    {
        printf( "Kort%zu: %d %d\n", i + 1, kort[i].kuloer, kort[i].vaerdi );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is the same as you are expecting

```
Kort1: 3 2
Kort2: 3 3
Kort3: 3 4
Kort4: 3 5
Kort5: 3 6
Kort6: 3 7
Kort7: 3 8
Kort8: 3 9
Kort9: 3 10
Kort10: 3 11
Kort11: 3 12
Kort12: 3 13
Kort13: 3 14
Kort14: 4 2
Kort15: 4 3
Kort16: 4 4
Kort17: 4 5
Kort18: 4 6
Kort19: 4 7
Kort20: 4 8
Kort21: 4 9
Kort22: 4 10
Kort23: 4 11
Kort24: 4 12
Kort25: 4 13
Kort26: 4 14
//...
```